# How to select a worksheet if it contains a number

Tags: excel, vba

This seems like a basic question but have been unable to troubleshoot or find anything online.  I have a macro that creates sheets based on a customer number.  The sheets I need to manipulate are customer number sheets, the remaining sheets have text names.  Is it possible to identify the sheet names that are numeric in nature?  The customer names are all 6 digits but other than that can be any combination of numbers.

I have looked online and all I can find are loops using some type of constant name or number to select the given sheet.

Example sheet names:

```
606278    705213    134875   MainInformation
```

Is there anyway to select these sheets given there is no numbering convention, only that they are always 6 digits?

Comment: `If sht.Name like "######" Then...`

Comment: I have the sudden urge to shout danger Will Robinson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this as an example:

```
Public Sub DoWorkbooks()
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If Len(wks.Name) = 6 And IsNumeric(wks.Name) Then

        Debug.Print wks.Name
      End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What about "44.677" and "123E10" ?